# What is wrong with my image slideshow? - Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've coded a simple image slideshow using Vanilla JS which unfortunately isn't working. It's structured in a 'section', within a 'container'. The overflow of the container is hidden, and there are relative 'span' circles below it which I want to use to control the slideshow.

Here is my code so far:

```js
// Variables

let i;
let image = document.getElementsByClassName("image");
let slideIndex = 1;
let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dots");


// Functions

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showImage(n) {
  if (n > image.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = image.length;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
    image[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace("active", "");
  }
  image[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].classList.add("active");
}

showImage(slideIndex);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.image-section {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #303960;
}

.image-container {
  height: 600px;
  width: 900px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.image {
  height: 600px;
  width: 900px;
}

.image-controller {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.dots {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  background-color: #f96d80;
}
```

```html
  <section class="image-section">
      <div class="image-container">
        <div class="image" style="background-color: black">

        </div>
        <div class="image" style="background-color: red">

        </div>
        <div class="image" style="background-color: blue">

        </div>
        <div class="image" style="background-color: orange">

        </div>
        <div class="image" style="background-color: purple">

        </div>
        <div class="image" style="background-color: brown">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="image-controller">
        <span class="dots active" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
        <span class="dots" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
        <span class="dots" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
        <span class="dots" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
        <span class="dots" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>
        <span class="dots" onclick="currentSlide(6)"></span>
      </div>
    </section>
```

I'm assuming it's a problem with my for loop, but I could be wrong. Any advice would be great!

Comment: how are you executing the showImage function?. `dots[slideIndex-1].style.display = "active";` that is invalid, and it should be `dots[slideIndex-1].classList.add("active")`

Comment: From where you are calling showImage function ?

Comment: I wasn't - but having added it in, and passing in slideIndex it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was this something you had in mind? You made the code a bit too complex.

I changed everything in your javascript code, because nothing really worked with all your different method names and how they were called. Thought it was easier for me to just type a few lines of code to show a different way of thinking.

---

Your `images` (it should be called "images", not "image" because there are several of them) and `dots` arrays start at position 0, so use that. Start by adding `0` as a parameter in your onclick method on your first dot element.

Then just keep track of the previous index (`prevSelection`) and remove the `.active` class from the previously selected image and dot, while adding `.active` to the newly selected image and dot. I added CSS style for `.active` for `.image`.

If you want to add a sliding animation, this is not the way to go, however.

```js
// Variables

let images = document.getElementsByClassName("image");
let dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dots");

var prevSelection = 0;

function showSlides(slidePosition) {
  removeClass('active', prevSelection);
  addClass('active', slidePosition);
  
  prevSelection = slidePosition;
}

function removeClass(className, slidePosition) {
  dots  [slidePosition].classList.remove(className);
  images[slidePosition].classList.remove(className);
}

function addClass(className, slidePosition) {
  dots  [slidePosition].classList.add(className);
  images[slidePosition].classList.add(className);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.image-section {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #303960;
}

.image-container {
  height: 600px;
  width: 900px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.image {
  display: none;
  height: 600px;
  width: 900px;
}

.image.active { /* added this */
  display: block;
}

.image-controller {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.dots {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dots.active { /* added .dots for better clarity */
  background-color: #f96d80;
}
```

```html
<section class="image-section">
      <div class="image-container">
        <div class="active image" style="background-color: black">

        </div>
        <div class="image" style="background-color: red">

        </div>
        <div class="image" style="background-color: blue">

        </div>
        <div class="image" style="background-color: orange">

        </div>
        <div class="image" style="background-color: purple">

        </div>
        <div class="image" style="background-color: brown">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="image-controller">
        <span class="active dots" onclick="showSlides(0)"></span>
        <span class="dots" onclick="showSlides(1)"></span>
        <span class="dots" onclick="showSlides(2)"></span>
        <span class="dots" onclick="showSlides(3)"></span>
        <span class="dots" onclick="showSlides(4)"></span>
        <span class="dots" onclick="showSlides(5)"></span>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Thanks - this is absolutely perfect. Really appreciate the help. The bit I was struggling with was getting the 'dots' to align to the relevant 'image'. I'm not bothered about a sliding effect - just for users to be able to flick between slides themselves without a timer. Thanks again!

Comment: I think what happened was that you never removed `display: block` from the first black background, which "pushed" all the other slides to the side. You couldn't see that because you had `overflow: hidden` on the container element.